# Issue with c code not displaying the array correctly language C

Tags: c

Using C programming, write a program that randomly generates a number between 1 and 10 and pass the number generated and any other number of your choosing to a sum function. The sum function should return the result of the two numbers and store it in an array. The program should run recursively until all numbers between 1 and 10 is generated and their sum stored in the array. (Hint: No randomly generated number should be used twice, even though it can be generated more than once).

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    int array[11], limit = 11; 
    int array_sum[11];
    int num = 0;
    int sum_n = 0, sum = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int a = 0;
    size_t n = 11;     
    size_t i;

    for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) array[i] = i;
    while(count <= 10)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) 
        {
            srand(time(NULL));
            count++;
            size_t pick;
            num = pick = rand() % n;
            printf("%d\n", array[pick]);
            array[pick] = array[--n];
            printf("Please enter a number to add: ");
            scanf("%d, ", &sum_n);
            array_sum[a] = sum_n + num;
            a++;
        }
        
    }
    printf("There is no element left to print");
    for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        printf("%d", array_sum[i]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yaf30.png)

Comment: You are using `srand` incorrectly. Only call it _once_, not in the loop.

Comment: By calling `srand` with the current time inside the loop, you will seed the random number generator and cause it to emit the same pseudo-random number until the time advances to the next second. Call `srand` once at the beginning of your program.

Comment: "The program should run recursively..." - I don't see any sign of recursion in this code.

Comment: What input are you using? What output are you expecting? What output are you getting?

Comment: @FredLarson The input is already given as a range from 0 to 10 and the output should be an array with 11 elements(the random numbers are added to a number inputted by the user)

Comment: I also see no attempt made to check if the randomly generated number already has been. My non-recursive solution for this would involve initializing the array with -1 and generate the number. If that location is -1, you know it's new. Otherwise, try again. Not quite sure what you're trying to accomplish with the double loops, especially since `count` is incremented in the inner loop. You can't just loop from 1 to 10, you don't know how many iterations it will take. You need a construct like `while (numbersLeftToGenerate() ){ ... }`, then adapt that for recursion.

Comment: @yano the array[--n] removes whatever number was chosen

Comment: hmm maybe I'm misunderstanding the requirements. I read it as "I need to generate random numbers until 1 thru 10 are generated". If you're playing by the rules, you don't know how many loop iterations that will take. It could take 10 (best case scenario), it could take 1000. Of course, in the end, numbers 1 thru 10 will be generated. If you want to jump straight to that step there's no point in generating anything ;)